# Java Constructor Skipped Over In Debugger

Tags: java, class

I have a class with 4 private fields: 3 are int, 1 is a String. My class has only one explicit constructor and that constructor takes in a string which is then assigned to the 1 String field. The other 3 fields use the value of the String fields' length() along with other literal ints to be assigned default values. I keep getting a "NullPointerException" and when I follow the code through the debugger, my program seems like it isn't even entering the constructor and so when it goes to set the 3 int variables, the length of the string is null because it is not given a default value. How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code will explain better than hundred words, post your code here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're initializing instance variables of your class directly where you declare them (like `var1`), referencing another instance variable declared above them (`name`) - which you initialize in the constructor.  The problem is that Java rules state that the instance initializer expressions are actually evaluated before the constructor is called - so at the time Java is trying to compute the value for `var1`, name does not yet have a value, because (you were right) the constructor has not yet been called.

You can move the expressions that initialize all your variables that depend on `name` into the constructor proper.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Khemraj that posting your code would help us answer this. However, there are two simple options I can think of, given what you have posted:

1) (Not ideal) Assign a default value to your string. That will ensure that it has a length, and that the other fields can be set. That being said, I'm not sure on the context whether this string is final, the ints are final, etc; if they are, this will probably mess up your object you're trying to construct, as it will permanently have the wrong values associated with it.

2) (Better Practice) **Don't put 'logic' in your constructor.** Set up your constructor to initialize the object with a string, and the int fields set to 0. Then create a method that sets the int fields according to the string's length that null-checks the string prior to calculating the length:

```
public void setLengths() {
    if (objectString != null) {
        // Example processes to perform based on string's length:
        objectIntOne = objectString.length();
        objectIntTwo = objectString.length() + 5;
        objectIntThree = objectString.length() - 3;
    }
    else {
        // Whatever you want to do if you don't have a valid string
    }
```

Comment: I don’t think it’s a common practice, but why not put a bill check into your constructor directly that throws an exception if a null string is passed in? That way it forces the object at instantiation to contain a usable strong from which the int values can be calculated?